# Null Pointer Exception while choosing file

Tags: java, android-intent, nullpointerexception

I am writing a contact form in which I am creating a file picker with a button, but the problem is that if file size is large, its unfortunately stops and if there is no file explorer than its giving null pointer exception.
Here is the code of intent

```
Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);

            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);// its optional
            intent.setType("image/*");
            final int SELECT_IMAGE = 1;
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select  Picture"), SELECT_IMAGE);
and here is the code of on activity result
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        try {

           if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {


                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};

                Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();

                int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
                String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
                cursor.close();

     //this code converts image in base64 and the string is to be sent along post method:
                yourSelectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
                try {
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    yourSelectedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                    byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
                    encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, resultCode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Add stacktrace and mark the line where the exception is thrown.

Comment: 5924-5924/darteweb.cqc E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: (Heap Size=32803KB, Allocated=29166KB)

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace using the edit funktion.